# Cast SynchronizedCollection<T> to read only SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, collections, concurrency

I had a `List<T>`, used `AsReadOnly()` method and stored the result in `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Now I work in threads and need to do the same but with `SynchronizedCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` and `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SynchronizedCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>` you could initialize the new instance of the `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>` based on your existing `SynchronizedCollection<T>` using the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedreadonlycollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection_1__ctor)

```
var readOnlyCollection = new SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection(synchronizedCollection.SyncRoot,
                                                            syncronizedCollection);
```

I am also thinking about another approach. The difference is that with the first approach you really have the snapshot of the `SynchronizedCollection<T>` but with this one, you have just a read-only wrapper(if you add something to original collection it will update also the read-only collection)

```
public static class SynchronizedCollectionExtension
{
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnly<T>(this SynchronizedCollection<T> value)
    {
        lock (value.SyncRoot)
        {
            // this call is not expensive as it is just a thin wrapper around the IList<T>
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(value);
        }
    }
}

IReadOnlyCollection<int> readOnlyCollection = collection.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I do it without creating a new object? If I have a property to access the collection as readonly it is quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the data in an enumerable type then just pass it into the synchronized class constructors:

```
List<T> data = new List<T>();

var syncRoot = new object();
var syncCollection = new SynchronizedCollection<T>(syncRoot, data);

var synchronizedReadOnlyCollection = new SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>(syncRoot, data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I do it without creating a new object? If I have a property to access the collection as readonly it is quite expensive.

Comment: Just store the sync collection as a member variable.

Comment: I mean this `new SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>(syncRoot, data);`